# Is Midnight Commander tool a convenient software to have on a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, midnight-commander

I heard some opinions that `mc` cannot be installed on a Linux server just because somebody wants to.

My point is: The MC is quite a convenient tool to use, very useful and powerful, with a helpful interface, and it should be installed by default, or installed just on demand. I'm feeling like a handless without it, having to cope with `cd`, `cp`, `mv` commands all the time and `vim` instead of `mcedit` (which unfortunately I used to use for a long time and which is much easier than vim).

Am I right, that it is very convenient to have it in a Linux dev environment? Or I'm just wrong, and it is not very common software among the developers and Linux users, and I have to use more basic shell commands instead?

Comment: We don't really encourage questions that ask for opinions. It might be unusual for Linux professionals to use MC, but *what does it matter*? Where is the practical problem you want to solve? It surely would be good for you to learn basic Unix commands at some point, but it depends on what personal goals you want to achieve and what environment you work in.

Comment: @slhck I know basic commands, I'm writing shell scripts. But, I have a feeling that I spend more time typing command cp with all needed arguments instead of just pressing F5 in mc. So it's not the question of ability, it's question about efficiency

Comment: I understand. Well, in a way MC can be convenient for anybody. It's hard to answer the question. There's in fact no reason *not* to include it in a distribution except for saving space, but since few people (at least professionals) use it, it also makes sense to leave it out.

Comment: @slhck Ok, so maybe I want to hear the real arguments, why only few people (at least professionals) use it? They like to look like linux geeks typing and typing in the console? it's some sort of snobism? :)

Comment: I don't know – (un)fortunately, Super User is not a discussion forum. I'm sure you can visit [chat] or the [unix.SE] chat and ask people what they think about it though ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to, then use it. Most linux developers do not, but  But you should be proficient with the command-line utilities as well in case you need to use someone else's system, or if you need to write a shell script which would not be able to interact with the MC interface. `vim` isn't the only option - `emacs` is another full-functioned text editor and `nano` is a simple, barebones option, both available by default on most linux installations.

Comment: thanks for nano, I didn't knew about it. Looks like it has more human helpful interface than vim/emacs

Comment: and I'm quite proficient in writing scripts, but it's just easier to not spending the time typing all that commands

Comment: Good. You just don't want to get to the point where you're using MC as a crutch rather than a tool, so you can still work without it if you're forced to. Scripting is one example of that.

Comment: I can work without it of course. I just know that typing long command (for example. You have to copy some files from one folder to another. And, you forget the location of folder. tab is not an option, you can spend ages sorting out right folder if you just forgot the name. You probably will need to run some ls commands before cp. INSTEAD, in mc, you just press some 'insert' several times, one 'tab' and then F5!) takes more time than doing it in the MC